# Monitor file changes in windows xp issues in Python

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I want to monitor if the file has been changed through using watchdog in Python, however, when I test, the terminal give me a warning,

```
"C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\__init__.py:89:UserWarning:Failed to import read_directory_changes. Fall back to polling.warning.warn("Failed to import read_directory_changes. Fall back to polling")"
```

I've installed `pip` to install `watchdog`, however, I still don't know how this problem occur.

here is the test code:

```
# coding=utf-8
import sys
import time
import logging
import urllib
import urllib2
import os
# import MySQLdb
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

print "hello"
```

Comment: by the way, is there any good suggestion for monitoring the file changes in windows xp? Thank you!

Comment: I think the problem is in from watchdog.observers import Observer